# Vectores en lenguaje de c

Tags: c

Necesito ayuda en un programa en c, en el cual permita encontrar los K menores de un vector de tamaño N, donde k,N y todos los numeros del vector son ingreados por teclado 
considere que k<=N.

Ejemplo: `k=3` , `n=10` y el vector ingresado es `{4,2,7,4,8,9,2,5,1,3}`
solucion :numero menores son :1,2,2

y este es mi codigo

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    int n;
    int k,i,vector[n];


    printf("ingrese el tamaño del vector N : \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){


    printf("ingrese %d valores en vector : \n",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&vector[n]);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Tienes tarea y codigo pero lo cual nos mas interesa - el problema que tengas - lo faltas de esplicar.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centrándome solo en la inicialización de tu vector:

Estás declarando una formación con una variable no inicializada y que no es constante, para usar:

`int vector[n]`

`n` debe haber sido inicializado como un valor constante, por ejemplo `const int n=10`, si no es así, esa línea no compilará, para inicializar una formación con un tamaño variable (que vas a obtener por teclado), podrías usar la función `malloc` o `calloc` ambos en la librería `stdlib.h`, la diferencia entre ambas es que `malloc` no inicializa los elementos y `calloc`, llamada en la forma:

```
vector = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

Inicializará todos los elementos a cero, que en este caso sería lo más recomendable, dicho esto, la forma correcta, a mi parecer, para crear `vector` luego de haber ingresado el valor de `n` sería:

```
if (n > 0)
    vector = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
else {
    printf("Valor ingresado no válido");
    exit(-1);
}
```

También podrías crear un bucle para insistir hasta que se ingrese un valor válido, luego para ingresar los elementos:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("ingrese %d valores en vector : \n", i + 1);
    scanf("%i", &vector[i]);
}
```

El código completo para terminar la inicialización de tu vector sería:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    int k, i,*vector;

    printf("ingrese el tamaño del vector N : \n");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    if (n > 0)
        vector = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    else {
        printf("Valor ingresado no válido");
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("ingrese %d valores en vector : \n", i + 1);
        scanf("%i", &vector[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Respecto a lo otro, intenta resolver tu problema primero de forma lógica (en papel) y luego intenta llevarlo a código, debes demostrar cierto interés e investigación de tu parte, si durante el proceso te encuentras con problemas, puedes recurrir aquí para ayudarte.

Comment: *por ejemplo const int n=10, si no es así, esa línea no compilará...* No es del todo cierto. Los [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) es una caracteristica del estándar C99 de C. Por lo tanto, es válido usarlo en lenguaje C. El inconveniente ocurre que depende del compilador si lo implementa o no.